# Regular expression for parsing the sections in the wikipedia markup?

Tags: java, regex, string, wikipedia

I have a wikipedia markup string of the following form -

```
String wikiPediaMarkupString = "==Early life== === GOD === ==== GReat ====";
```

I need to write a regex such that I get only the strings -: Early Life , GOD and GReat as output and not the spaces betwwen the equal to signs, and I am really confused as to how to formulate the regex for this problem. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Try `split(" *=[= ]*")`.  This splits your string into the parts between the delimiters, where the regex defines a delimiter as a sequence of spaces and `=` signs that contains at least one `=` (the regex looks for zero or more spaces, followed by `=`, followed by any number of spaces or `=`).

Comment: If you need to check whether there are at least two `=`'s together, then `split(" *==[= ]*")`.  But it appears (from your comment) that you may need to think more about what the exact requirements are.

Comment: Well to tell you the specific problem I am dealing with, its the following - I have a wikipedia XML file like this - http://pastebin.com/esarwZD2 and I have to parse out the sections and the text that follows the section into  section objects which have 2 fields "Section Title" and "Section Text" a section in wikipedia XML begins with '==' , '===' or '====' followed by the section title and ends also with the same characters now how do I do that using regex?